# how do I implement the library charts_flutter 0.10.0?

Tags: function, flutter, charts, libraries, program-entry-point

thanks for taking the time looking at my thread.

Well I'm really new on the dart language and I was looking to implement graphs on my app. I found this library charts_flutter 0.10.0 and started to look on the documentation to implement on my app. Unfortunately when I tried copying the code from an example and trying to understand how it behave I found that the actual code doesn't has a main function to start the app, so I was looking for help on this part because I have no clue of how should I implement this chart widget on an main function.

For example, the Horizontal Bar Label Custom Bar Chart Example code is this one:

```
/// Horizontal bar chart with custom style for each datum in the bar label.
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HorizontalBarLabelCustomChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  HorizontalBarLabelCustomChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [BarChart] with sample data and no transition.
  static HorizontalBarLabelCustomChart createWithSampleData() {
    return new HorizontalBarLabelCustomChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  // The [BarLabelDecorator] has settings to set the text style for all labels
  // for inside the bar and outside the bar. To be able to control each datum's
  // style, set the style accessor functions on the series.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      vertical: false,
      barRendererDecorator: new charts.BarLabelDecorator<String>(),
      // Hide domain axis.
      domainAxis:
          new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', 5),
      new OrdinalSales('2015', 25),
      new OrdinalSales('2016', 100),
      new OrdinalSales('2017', 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
        // Set a label accessor to control the text of the bar label.
        labelAccessorFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) =>
            '${sales.year}: \$${sales.sales.toString()}',
        insideLabelStyleAccessorFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) {
          final color = (sales.year == '2014')
              ? charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault
              : charts.MaterialPalette.yellow.shadeDefault.darker;
          return new charts.TextStyleSpec(color: color);
        },
        outsideLabelStyleAccessorFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) {
          final color = (sales.year == '2014')
              ? charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault
              : charts.MaterialPalette.yellow.shadeDefault.darker;
          return new charts.TextStyleSpec(color: color);
        },
      ),
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

And whit my little knowledge of the language I tried to make a

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

but obviously I need the actual MyApp function which I don't know if it's a statless or stateful widget, I don't even know how do I put the widget on the main app function so basically I'm completely lost on this code. Please if someone can help me, I would apreciate it a lot

Comment: you need to add the `HorizontalBarLabelCustomChart` as a child of `MyApp`. Please follow the tutorial at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

Comment: I tried that, but when I put it as a child HorizontalBarLabelCustomChart() it spects a value